# Kubernetes - Is Nginx Ingress, Proxy part of k8s core?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I understand there are various ways to get external traffic into the cluster - Ingress, cluster IP, node port and load balancer. I am particularly looking into the Ingress and k8s and from the documentation k8s `supports` AKS, EKS & Nginx controllers.

```
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/
```

To implement Ingress, understand that we need to configure an Ingress Controller in the cluster. My query is whether Nginx ingress & proxy are an offering of core k8s (packaged / embedded)? Might have overlooked, did not find any documentation where it is mentioned. Any insight or pointer to documentation if stated above is true is highly appreciated.

Comment: [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) shows an example of creating an ingress in kubernetes. All you need is to deploy that yaml file.

Comment: @sadsad Thanks, I understand that. My question was around whether Nginx comes packaged as a part of core K8s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reading the first rows of the page you linked, it states that no controller are started automatically with a cluster and that you must choose the one of your preference, depending on your requirements

> Ingress controllers are not started automatically with a cluster. Use
> this page to choose the ingress controller implementation that best
> fits your cluster.

Kubernetes defines `Ingress`, `IngressClass` and other ingress-related resources but a fresh installation does not come with any default.

Some prepackaged installation of Kubernetes (like microk8s, minikube etc...) comes with ingress controller that, usually, needs to be enabled manually during the installation/configuration phase.